# Ring theory and particular euclidean ring

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $J(i):=\{a+bi\in \mathbb{C}|a,b\in \mathbb{Z}\}$. I want to prove:

> If $a+bi$ is not a unit of $J(i)$ then $a^2+b^2> 1$.

I have just started to study the ring theory even though the question might be too easy I need your help. first what is unit of $J(i)$? Second which properties of ring I need to use to show $a^2+b^2> 1$.

Thanks.

Comment: First of all, please use $\LaTeX$. Second of all, what is $J$? Also, in a general ring, it doesn't make sense to say whether one object is "greater" than another.

Comment: it's an Euclidean ring, so each element has a norm.

Comment: J(i) is the set of complex number of the form a+bi where a,b in Z.

Comment: oh, it made much more sense.

Answer (score 1):

The units of $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ are elements such that there exists an inverse, i.e.: elements of the form $a+bi$ such that there exists $c+di$ satisfying: $(a+bi)(c+di) = 1$. 
For example: $i$ is a unit because there exists $-i$, and $i \cdot (-i) = 1$.

Suppose $a^2+b^2 \le 1$. Can you find $a$ and $b$? Then what are $a+bi$? 
Are they units?

Comment: how about 0+0i by looking your definition it is not unit since it is not invertible and also satisfies  a2+b2≤1.

Comment: Great. I assumed that a+bi different from 0. I think otherwise the problem will be wrong.